# Silverlight Datagrid not properly display data

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, linq, datagrid

So I made a datagrid in Silver that auto-generates columns. I call a WCF service that fills this data grid. It displays all but two of the columns. Does any know what causes this?

Here is the function that fulls my class that is bounded to

```
  public List<LightOrder> GetOrder(string code)
    {
        // Add your operation implementation here
        using (amazonproscoutEntities context = new amazonproscoutEntities())
        {
            return (from c in context.AmazonSKUs
                    where c.MerchantSKU.StartsWith(code)
                    select new LightOrder()
                    {
                        SKU = c.MerchantSKU,
                        productname = c.ItemName,
                        asin = c.ASIN,
                        //ourprice = c.OurPrice,
                        bbprice = c.Price,
                        quantity = c.TotalQty,
                        rank = c.Rank,
                        amazon = c.Amazon,
                        afner = c.AFNer
                        //w1 = c.w1

                    }
                    ).Take<LightOrder>(500).ToList<LightOrder>();

        }
    }
```

This is the class that is bound the the data grid:

```
public class LightOrder
{
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string productname { get; set; }
    public string itemnumber { get; set; }
    public string asin { get; set; }
    public string amazon { get; set; }
    public decimal ourprice { get; set; }
    public string bbprice { get; set; }
    public int w1 { get; set; }
    public string w2 { get; set; }
    public string w3 { get; set; }
    public string w4 { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string pendingorder { get; set; }
    public string afner { get; set; }
    public string order { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string profit { get; set; }
    public string percent { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: " It displays all but two of the columns." what you mean by this, it shows data of only two columns ?

Comment: @Ovais "all but" it actually means the opposite. Everything except those two columns. The columns are rank and amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is the class that is having the issue. It has seemingly ignored those fields.

Answer (score 0):

Are these 2 columns marked by the [DataMember] attribute?

If you marked it, and they are still not appearing, maybe the service reference wasn't generated properly?

Comment: I am kind of confused by what you are asking.